# Can I migrate all data from my MacBook to my iMac

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, imac, migration

How can I migrate all data from my MacBook to my iMac without losing it from the Macbook?

Comment: The problem with this approach is that you will copy all of your configuration data as well which may just retrigger the Mail issue on the new Mac.

Comment: That, and his drive will fill up with duplicate data.

Answer (score 2):

Goto Application > Utilities > Migration Assistant on both the devices, they should be either on the same wifi network, or connected physically with a Cable like thunderbolt, Ethernet etc. It will guide you to transfer the data.